# Google places autocomplete, use without their maps

Tags: google-api, google-places-api, mapbox, google-places

Anyone knows if I can use google places autocomplete and use MapBox as the map and not Google map? 
By doing so am I violating google places terms of use?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you render Places data on a map, it *has* to be a google map.

However, you can render data without a map, but this required a "Powered by google" logo.

> If your application displays Places API data on a map, that map must
>   be provided by Google.
>
> If your application displays Places API data on a page or view that
>   does not also display a Google Map, you must show a "Powered by
>   Google" logo with that data. For example, if your application displays
>   a list of Places on one tab, and a Google Map with those Places on
>   another tab, the first tab must show the "Powered by Google" logo.

https://developers.google.com/places/policies